# What issues can arise from checking in .vssscc and .vspscc files into source control?

Tags: version-control, tfs

There seems to be some consternation about two file types that, in my case, TFS checks in when a new solution or project are created: .vssscc and .vspscc files.

[I found a page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9920911d-1a7e-4ada-90cd-b1b910586cf4/why-do-you-need-the-vspscc-and-vssscc-files?forum=tfsgeneral) that describes that these files are for, and [yet another](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d54e7126-eb15-4616-a2b6-afc71dc25fcf/should-we-normally-check-source-control-files-vssscc-vspscc-in-?forum=tfsversioncontrol) that recommends checking them in. I'm perfectly fine with this, but I have heard some grumblings in the internet that these files can cause issues with collaboration between projects, such as merge conflicts and project load errors.

I do recall having some issues in my own organization where the .vspscc file caused some issues, where a developer had caused some edits to it and didn't check it in with the rest of his changes. We were able to repair easily, however.

My question is: what issues should I be aware of, and in the case that issues exist, what precautions can I recommend to my organization to avoid any trouble?

Comment: Also: I opened an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1801, so go there and let them know how this affects you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only issue I've ever come across is a minor annoyance- the .vssscc is included as a change with many checkins even though the .vssscc contents have not changed. I'm guessing the last modified date is being updated.

[Apparently Microsoft was looking into fixing this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9920911d-1a7e-4ada-90cd-b1b910586cf4/#e3436550-153e-4a06-ad68-ba998b08a13c) in 2010.

It seems unlikely that these files contain anything of importance to the source code. As far as I can tell it's just cached data about the current code.

I opened an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1801, so go there and let them know how this affects you.